# Alternative to [0-9] to only match match digit 5 and 7

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to query rows where `s3_log_path` column contains values `20231225` and `20231227`, and the requirement is we must use the REGEXP function (so no `LIKE` function such as `s3_log_path like '%20231225%' or occurrence_date like '%20231227%'`)

Comment: Sure, @BarbarosÖzhan. I'm using Snowflake, and I added that as a tag.

Comment: These are dates. Use actual date columns and comparisons. Storing dates in string columns is a recipe for slow and error-prone code.

Comment: “*the requirement is we must use the REGEXP function*” Certainly outside the scope of the question as asked, but… why…? Regular expressions will almost certainly be less performant than `LIKE`, and both will be *significantly* less performant than treating these values properly as the dates they are.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn the column is actually S3 log path, not date. I apologize originally wrote occurrence_date. I just updated the column name in question.

Comment: I also just remembered Snowflake has `CONTAINS` which would also be much more preferable than using regular expressions for this.

Comment: @esqew, I realize that too, and I agree using LIKE and CONTAINS will be more performant than REGEXP, but this is more of a intellectual understanding for me to learn more about the possibilities with REGEXP.

Comment: @Stanleyrr parse out the date and write it to it's own column when inserting the record. It really is worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So using [REGEXP](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp) which is an inline syntax not a function you can use a multi-match `[]` , but an alternative to this is to use a Group `()` with an Or inside `|`.

Next thing to note REGEXP is an alias for [RLIKE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/rlike) witch has the format of a function, and allows parameters to control it's behavior, so is the superior form, thus those two patterns can be used there.

thus the following SQL shows some options:

```
select 
    $1 as s3_log_path
    ,s3_log_path regexp '.*2023122[57].*' as r1
    ,s3_log_path regexp '.*2023122(5|7).*' as r2
    ,RLIKE(s3_log_path, '.*2023122[57].*') as rl1
    ,RLIKE(s3_log_path, '.*2023122(5|7).*') as rl2
from values
    ('yes match 20231225 end text'),
    ('also match 20231227 end text'),
    ('no_match 2031227 end text')
```

[image]